# Issue regarding image and text properties html/css

Tags: html, css

```html
  <h2 style="margin-left: 440px; margin-top: 206px; cursor:pointer; padding: 5px; position: fixed" class="textShare">Share</h2> // The text
   <img class="textdownvote" id="textDownvoteImg" src="img/downvote.png" alt="downvote" onclick="changetextDownvote()" style="width: 120px; margin-top: -12px; position: fixed; cursor: pointer"> // The image
```

I have a transparent image (an icon) and some text right above it. Now, when you hover on that text, it should turn orange. Now, when you hover on the top region of the text, it's turning orange. However, when you hover on the bottom region of the text, it doesn't turn orange because the image occupies that area. I don't want this to happen. I should be able to hover wherever on the text and it should turn orange, but now, I can only hover on the top of the text, because the image doesn't occupy *that* text, but it does occupy the bottom region, so when you hover there, the text doesn't turn orange.

The only problem is that I can't move the image or the text left or right or up or down, because that will completely ruin my design layout. Furthermore, I can't even change the width or height of the image because that will stretch the image and change how it looks. Taking both of these aspects into consideration, I want the image to remain exactly the same; not to look different by not stretching it; and hover anywhere on the text for it to turn orange. With no other options, I'm puzzled. Here's my code:

```
<div style="margin-left: 715px; position: fixed; font-family: 'Rajdhani'">
  <h2 style="margin-left: 440px; margin-top: 206px; cursor:pointer; padding: 5px; position: fixed" class="textShare">Share</h2> // The text
 </div>
 <div style="position: fixed; margin-left: 1063px; margin-top: 285px">
   <img class="textupvote" id="textUpvoteImg" src="img/upvote.png" alt="upvote" onclick="changetextUpvote()" style="width: 100px; margin-bottom: 28px; cursor: pointer">  // Ignore this image; below image is what I'm talking about
   <img class="textdownvote" id="textDownvoteImg" src="img/downvote.png" alt="downvote" onclick="changetextDownvote()" style="width: 120px; margin-top: -12px; position: fixed; cursor: pointer"> // The image
 </div>
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you make a runnable snippet? ... use the `<>` icon on the editor toolbar to create one.

Comment: I did make a snippet, you could use it and change it around to identify my issue and the solution.

Comment: The snippit doesnt display the problem correctly. The styles are missing and its very unclear what your problem is. if the image is overlaying the text, put the text on top (z-index), of cancel the pointer events on the image (pointer-events:none)..  but again, very unclear what you want to achieve....

Comment: Crop your images that will solved your problem

Comment: @ShubhamRaturi It did. Thanks a lot!